# how do I convert array to JSON

Tags: python, json

I wonder how to convert array to JSON
I have array has bulk of urls.

```
urllist = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com'.....]
```

and I would like to convert urllist to JSON format like this

```
 value= 
 {
 "entry": [
    {
        "url": "http://www.riskiq.com/"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://www.riskiq.net/"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://localhost/"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://sf.riskiq.net/"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://www.riskiq.net/"
    }
 ]
}
```

what is the way to convert it.
Thanks you in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking for a json encoder/decoder library for python?

Comment: Here is the json library docs for converting to json http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: The "array" you show as input isn't a valid Python list or JSON array or anything else I can think of. And for your output, is `value=` supposed to be part of the JSON?

Comment: Meanwhile, the answer to "How do I convert this thing to this JSON format?" is always the same for any (valid) format: Figure out the appropriate Python dict/list/etc. structure, build _that_, then call `json.dumps` on it. So, if you're asking about JSON formats, you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import json
>>> url_list = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com']
>>> json.dumps({'entry': [{'url': v} for v in url_list]})
'{"entry": [{"url": "http://www.google.com"}, {"url": "http://www.yahoo.com"}]}'

>>> print json.dumps({'entry': [{'url': v} for v in url_list]}, indent=4)
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "url": "http://www.google.com"
        }, 
        {
            "url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

The amount of whitespace isn't significant in json. If you want a fancy format, you'll have to do some work yourself